# Where to get full gdb binary for Android?

Tags: android, gdb

For debugging Android apps with gdb I want to use the standalone version of gdb directly on the Android device.

**Is there any pre-built binary version of gdb for Android available?**

Note that I am searching for the full gdb version for Android, **not the crippled gdbserver**.

Background: I know that the Android NDK includes gdbserver, however if you don't debug your own programs you have source code for setting up gdbserver and of gdb host part is fairy complex. I tried it a long time but now I am done with it - it adds too many complexity and pitfalls to the whole debugging process.

Furthermore I tried to build gdb on my own using the standalone-toolchain generated by android-ndk - but th process fails because of code errors.

Comment: It strikes me as pretty unlikely that you will find an existing android build.  I think you will find getting gdb itself to cross compile for android substantially more complicated than learning to use gdb server.  One possible exception would be one of the traditional-linux-runtime-in-a-chroot setups, where gdb would be compiled against a normal libc, however you'd probably end up having to build Android's gdb on that platform to make it cooperate with bionic's linker for the code being debugged, and the chroot might make things tricky.