# Compile GDB binary for android - Is it possible?

Tags: android, compilation, android-ndk, gdb

I am trying to compile GDB (full version) so it can be run on an android.  I have looked at "[Where to get full gdb binary for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462488/where-to-get-full-gdb-binary-for-android)" and understand that it will be tough (It has been so far). I have downloaded the NDK but am not able to successfully compile it for android.  Can anyone tell me if it is possible, or am I wasting my time on trying to compile it?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you succeeded? Did you use Google GDB code or Apportable?

Answer (score 1):

The android gdb source is available [here](https://android.googlesource.com/toolchain/gdb/).

I haven't directly built the Google source, but I have built the [Apportable gdb fork](https://github.com/apportable/gdb) (adds Objective C for Android debugging support)